# How do I take out the cops?

Tags: carmageddon

So it turns out the phrase *"you'll never take me alive, coppers"* is particularly apt in Carmageddon as they really have no interest in taking you alive. Ram, bash, charge, crash, KKND as opposed to Miranda rights.

I've upgraded my cars to almost max level (5/6 in Armour, Power and Offensive) but I still don't seem to be able to take out the cops, even with the Damage Magnifier active. I will occasionally get a few credits for dinging their bumper but no appreciable damage.

I remember them being tough, but I'm sure I was eventually able to take them out on a semi-regular basis*. I mostly drive the Eagle - is the car's relatively low Toughness rating (3) to blame? Should I be driving something heavier? Or is it simply not worth the cost in time and repair money?

* Was the cops' difficulty lowered in the sequels? Is that what I'm remembering?

Comment: which version of the game is this about as there are multiple versions and many of them dont have cops

Comment: @Callum Which versions don't have cops? They've always been a staple of the series in my experience.

Comment: it is covered here: http://carmageddon.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cops - n64 and playstation versions don't have cops

Comment: @Callum Interesting to know - though I'm not sure it adds much to the question - clearly this is about a version that _does_ have cops...

Comment: the versions that dont have ai cops have drivers in cop cars that are just normal racers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for the Android version on Easy mode, it's just a matter of taking them out just like you would take any other car out. The cops, however, have a much better AI than the other drivers (perhaps unsurprisingly) and their car is more like a tank than a car proper, so they take a *lot* of punishment before going down. Eventually, however, go down they will.

If you have the time and profits to spare you can simply hold the repairs button down as they automatically ram you into a wall. Eventually, they'll destroy their own car. You probably want to have tier 3 upgrades before trying, though.

Answer (score 1):

You wont do much damage to the police without the 'acme damage magnifier' or 'solid granite car'. The rest of the time it will feel like you are just bouncing off them. Once you got a power up you should try and kill them for sure 'cause you get lots of points for wasting one.

To take out the cops you need a lot of momentum. Think of it like a dog fight, they already got the upper hand 'cause they are coming after you so you need to turn it around on them. You need a run up for speed or a wall you can pin them against. Once you have them pinned, keep up the pressure. In a dead end, pin them against a wall and immediately back up to give you room to get some speed to ram them some more. Dont let them get behind you - keep them in view so you can charge them down again.